# How to Avoid Realm-JS Crashes in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

I'm working on a React Native 0.40 app that uses Realm JS 1.0.0. I am experiencing crashes when reading/writing and some odd behaviors. For example, one of the crashes only happens when I add a second record to the table.

When it crashes, the output prints:

```
<Error>: MY_APP(18085,0x7000075ce000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744073345937408) failed (error code=3)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

(this is on the iOS simulator)

I've worked with Realm in Swift projects in the past where I had to be aware not to pass objects or collections around and also to not use the same realm from multiple threads, etc. However, I don't think those issues apply to RN. Right?

My general approach is to have a Realm factory like:

**realm.js**

```
export function getUserRealm(){

    const realm = new Realm({
        schema: combinedSchemas,
        path: `main.realm`
    });

    console.log( " User Realm Path:", realm.path );

    return realm;

}
```

Then I call `getUserRealm()` from wherever it is that I'm using realm.

There are a few places where I do pass `Results` between functions and callbacks.

*The main question is*, what should I guard against in order to prevent crashes?

Comment: This sounds tricky to debug just from the code you've provided. Could you send a small repro project to help@realm.io?

Comment: Try adding a try catch and check the exception . The issue could be something wrong with the configuration.
`
export function getUserRealm() {
    try {
        const realm = new Realm({
            schema: combinedSchemas,
            path: 'main.realm',
        });

        console.log(' User Realm Path:', realm.path);

        return realm;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('ex', ex);
    }
}

`